# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'

Tags: python, fenics

i'm new to python on Mac and i need to solve PDEs. I saw that Fenics is right for me. When I open Spider and run the program, I get this warning:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'`

I guess Spider can't find Fenics, but I installed it correctly from the terminal. Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install fenics` and then restarting your IDE?

Comment: Are you using Spyder via Anaconda or as a standalone IDE?

Comment: I'm using Spider via Anaconda

Comment: @NuKeFluffy, no. I try now!

Comment: @NuKeFluffy it doesn't work :(

Comment: How did you install the module you want? Have you made any virtual environment?